# Extracting certain attributes from raster layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, raster-calculator

I have a raster layer which illustrates land use in Rwanda. I would like to be able to extract the cropland and make it a raster by itself. I have tried to extract it using the raster calculator, however it does not work for me.

I tried using these two formulas:

```
(9 <= "Landcover_raster" <= 10)*1 + ((9 > "Landcover_raster") AND ("Landcover_raster" > 10))*0
```

and

```
("Landcover_raster" = 0.21)*1 + ("Landcover_raster" != 0.21)*0
```

I was unsure whether I could extract it based on the value of the attribute or the label of the attribute.

Am I using the raster calculator wrong or is there another way to extract a certain attribute from a raster file?

Comment: What is the rastervalue of cropland?

Comment: There are two different kind of cropland, so the raster value is both 9 and 10. And then I have given them both the label 0.21, because that is the value that cropland should have in my formula.

Answer (score 1):

```
(("Landcover_raster"=9)+("Landcover_raster"=10))*.21
```

should work. It multiplies X by .21 where X is either 0 or 1, depending on whether it is land cover (9 or 10).

It is helpful to remember that with 1 and 0,

- OR is +,
- AND is *

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I needed! :-)

Comment: You can multiply by a million. The final number is unimportant :-)

Comment: @anneke: if an answer helped you solve your problem, you should accept it (hit the checkbox) and/or upvote it: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers